# Realm и наследование

Tags: java, android, realm

Мне необходимо хранить информацию по неким классам, которые, в свою очередь наследуются от других классов.

Насколько я знаю, в 2015 году разработчики Realm писали, что пока наследование не поддерживается, но его поддержка планируется в будущем.

Нашел информацию середины 2016-го года, в которой сказано, что наследование пока не поддерживается.

На актуальной версии Realm сохранить наследуемые объекты у меня не получается, но может просто я что-то делаю не так?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сейчас обстоят дела у Realm с наследованием?

Если поддержки наследования до сих пор нет, то может есть какие-нибудь менее-костыльные пути решения данной проблемы (без кардинального изменения существующего уровня модели в общем и без ее декомпозиции в частности)?

У меня есть одно решение, но хотелось бы узнать, как Вы решаете данную проблему.

Comment: В документации написано (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#field-types\ ) что в качестве полей модели Realm поддерживаются только простые типы, `String`, `Date` и `RealmObject`/`RealmList`/ Соответственно никакие прочие классы, с наследованием или нет, не могут быть полями модели в этой БД. Или я не понял вопрос ...

Comment: @pavlofff, Я не про поля. Я имел ввиду следующее: пусть есть `class A {...}` и `class B extends A {...}`, как сохранить в Realm объекты класса `B`?

Comment: То есть использовать класс `B` как модель, которая наследуется, но не от `RealmObject` или "положить" класс `B` как одно из полей в модели `RealmObject` ?

Comment: @pavlofff, Первое.

Comment: Вам нужно имплементировать [интерфейс `RealmModel`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface), а не наследовать от `RealmObject`, тогда модель может наследоваться от призвольного класса. [Пример](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761#issuecomment-258299398)

Comment: @pavlofff, Я так пробовал: `class A {...}`, `class B extends A  implements RealmModel {...}`. В итоге при компиляции получаю `error: Realm model classes must either extend RealmObject or implement RealmModel to be considered a valid model class` (ссылается на `class B`).

Comment: [Вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36920066/implementing-realmmodel-interface-while-extending-another-object) аналогичная проблема при использовании интерфейса.

Comment: Я сначала так и понял, мол если класс уже наследуется от какого-то класса, то, чтобы сохранить объекты этого класса, необходимо в нем реализовать интерфейс (так как множественного наследования нет), но с интерфейсом почему-то не работает и тогда я не понимаю вообще смысл данного интерфейса.

Comment: Ну раз заведен issue то видимо решения нет, остается ждать, когда исправят. Смысл RealmModel как раз в том, о чем в вашем вопросе, но что то пошло не так ...

Answer (score 1):

Рилм имеет поддержку имплементирования [RealmModel](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface) вместо наследования RealmObject классом модели. **Обратите внимание**, что нужно добавить аннотацию ***@RealmClass***, может именно по-этому и не работало... Как раз ваш случай?

Но вообще говоря, за год с лишним использования Рилма в продакшн проектах, у нас ни разу не возникало такой проблемы, чтобы пришлось имплиментить RealmModel. Возможно стоит пересмотреть иерархию классов ? Модели - это таблицы базы, может все таки не стоит, чтобы они наследовали некие другие обьекты, и преобретали дополнительное поведение, не относящееся к БД? Что если заменить наследование на реализацию интерфейса вашего класса А?

```
class B extends RealmObject implements A {
. . . 
// your fields
. . .
}
```

Просто, ну чего такого в этом классе А, чтобы его реально наследовать а не имплиментить интерфейс ?

Comment: Я знаю про этот интерфейс, но при его реализации появляются ошибки в процессе компиляции (посмотрите комментарии к вопросу). Класс аннотировал. У меня есть много способов решения данной проблемы, однако хотелось бы разобраться с непосредственным решением, которое предоставляет Realm.

Comment: Это очень странно. А вы пробовали на чистом классе, который никого не наследует？Вы используете модули рилма? Схемы？ иногда это важно.

Comment: Да, пробовал. Создавал чистый проект с добавлением одного простого класса, все равно не компилировалось.

Comment: Ну а прописывали именно модули рилма, где описанны классы, которые входят в модуль? А в схему нужно добавить нужные модули... детальнее на realm.io в разделе Configuring a Realm

Comment: Нет, использовалась дефолтная конфигурация. Вы думаете дело в этом? [Здесь](https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.89.0/) по этому поводу ничего не написано.

Comment: Может быть да, а может и нет. У нас были в одно время какие то странные штуки с рилмом, после данных манипуляций со схемами, все вылечилось. Да, еще нужно было некоторые к лассы, использовать только с аннотацией @RealmClass.  С тех пор, постоянно прописываем схемы и модули, проблем нет. Попробуйте, вдруг поможет, потому что мессадж ошибки говорит о том что вы не имплиментите интерфейс, хотя это неправда. Странно? Думаю да...

Comment: Да. Это весьма странно. Спасибо за идею, попробую.